# Execute php code on different server via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, node.js, sockets

As part of my third year project for university I am creating a HTML5 Web App for the amazon fire tv OS. This web app is supposed to communicate with another remote server to update another client with information about what the user is currently watching. I have succesfully implemented this communication using socket.io on localhost but unfortunately the android OS does not support web sockets, so I cannot use socket.io within the fire tv app itself.

To get around this I thought about having a php file on my server that will emit the socket request when a relevant GET request for the page is requested. The php code for the file is below:

```
if(isset($_GET['title'])){
    echo "
            socket.emit('vidStart', '" . $_GET['title'] . "');
    ";
}
echo "</script>";
```

As you can see all the code does is emit when the page is requested using a title parameter.

Now, this works fine when I go to the web browser myself and enter the url, the emit succeeds and my server receives the message.

However, I am trying to execute this on the server remotely using javascript, to get around having to use socket.io in my fire os app.

The code I currently have in my app is below:

```
$.ajax({
     'type': 'GET',
     'url': 'http://138.68.175.172:81',
     'data': 'title=example',
     success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
     }
});
```

This returns the correct response but doesnt seem to actually execute the php code and emit via socket io on my server. My question is, is this possible to do via javascript and php? I have tried looking at XMLWebRequest but it seems to do the same thing, and responds with the web page.

If this isn't possible, is there any other way to send information to a remote server, and have it execute a command ( in this case emit a socket.io message)?

Comment: Just as a heads up, you can use Socket IO on Android: http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

Comment: Hey, thanks for sharing that, I actually already know about this but I am really not willing to use the android fire app builder, it is such a headache, and I'd rather continue using the web app, thanks tho!

Comment: So the reason this works in your browser and not on the server is that it's your browser parsing the javascript which is output via php and emitting the request.  There are two ways you could do this (the way i see it).  One would be to use the built in PHP socket functionality: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php  the other would be to use Node.js which would probably be more familiar to you if you already use sockets via socket.io in the browser.

Comment: I agree with Dallas, you could have a simple node.js server running in 20 minutes that does what you need to achieve.